# Mann Whitney U coming out with same p values for different performance metrics

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have a dataset comparing two different treatment groups with several performance metrics (PM) expressed in percentage (see below). The Mann-Whitney U Test is the most appropriate test (discrete data, not normally distributed).

When I run my script (see below), many of the *p* values are coming out at the same value. This is strange, as I know the assumptions are met with the test, and I have used this script for previous data. Below I have given an example running three of the points. Points that give different *p* values are PM 2 (%), PM 6 (%), PM 11 (%).

Does anyone know where it's going wrong?

[image: Table of Data]

```
> wilcox.test(Dataset$`PM 1 (%)` ~ Dataset$`Treatment Group`, paired = FALSE)

    Wilcoxon rank sum exact test

data:  Dataset$`PM 1 (%)` by Dataset$`Treatment Group`
W = 0, p-value = 0.02857
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

> wilcox.test(Dataset$`PM 3 (%)` ~ Dataset$`Treatment Group`, paired = FALSE)

    Wilcoxon rank sum exact test

data:  Dataset$`PM 3 (%)` by Dataset$`Treatment Group`
W = 0, p-value = 0.02857
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

> wilcox.test(Dataset$`PM 7 (%)` ~ Dataset$`Treatment Group`, paired = FALSE)

    Wilcoxon rank sum exact test

data:  Dataset$`PM 7 (%)` by Dataset$`Treatment Group`
W = 0, p-value = 0.02857
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Comment: It appears as if in each test all elements in group 2 are larger then each element in group 1 so the Wlcoxon test sees an identical distribution of rank and thus gives identical p values.

Comment: Sorry if this comes across as uneducated, I'm still a beginner to the world of stats. So is what I have done correct?

Comment: Being a beginner is not a reason to apologize. I tried to make it clearer with an R example in my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that everything you have done is correct and you just foud out, that with small numbers there are only a few values a Wilcoxon p-value can take.

You will have many samples, where all values in group A are smaller then all values in group B as in the following example. The p-value will always be 0.028...

```r
A <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
B <- c(11, 12, 13, 14)

wilcox.test(A, B)$p.value
#> [1] 0.02857143
```

It doesn't matter, if the values differ more or less, as long as the ranks stay the same

```r
A <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
B <- c(1100, 1200, 1300, 1400)

wilcox.test(A, B)$p.value
#> [1] 0.02857143
```

It's still the same p-value, the same that you got. As long as your data follows this pattern, it is perfectly ok to get the exact same p-value from `wilcox.test`.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard. it's something I've not come across yet, glad to know I've followed the right steps

Comment: Great. If this answers your question, please feel free to accept it as explained in https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers